# The best way to deploy a MVC 3 site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I know this has been covered in in various questions and all over the internet, but I think everyone else had a specific problem in mind.  My situation is quit simple.

I have a naked Windows 2008 server with IIS7 and .NET 4.0 installed.  Fully Patched up.

I have turned off the Default Web Site in IIS7 (press Stop)

I have created a new site called "Portal" and a matching App Pool.  The app pool has been set to .NET 4.0 and it uses Integrated Pipeline, not Classic.

I have performed the /bin install of the MVC site.  I've got the MVC assemblies in the /bin folder.  I copied the files from my development machine to the appropriate folder in the server.

When I browse to the site, I get 403.14 Forbidden (can't list the contents of the folder.  When I browse to http://localhost/Dashboard (which is a routed page) I get a 404.

What am I missing?  Why doesn't IIS know to route the HTTP GET's to the MVC program and let the controllers work?

Comment: Have you installed MVC3 on the server?

Comment: I was under the impression that is not absolutely required.  So no, I haven't.  Are you saying that's required?

Comment: It's installed.  No change :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install MVC 3.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Comment: It's installed.  No Change :(

Comment: I had to reboot first :-)  Hey!  The installer didn't say so!